# ¿Cómo puedo poner una tabla muy larga, seccionarla y hacer que se vaya completando y el usuario siga avanzando?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, tabla-dinámica, carrusel

Estoy haciendo un proyecto para mi trabajo, es una prueba que deben contestar mis compañeros. Para esto hice un formulario con una tabla muy larga con todas las 40 preguntas. No se ve muy linda y puede ser intimidante.

Quiero fraccionarla en varias tablas con menos opciones y cuando los usuarios den su respuesta presionen siguiente, así es mas amigable. Lo intenté con un carrusel, pero llevo horas dándole vueltas porque el carrusel no me muestra nada. Quizá alguien podría darme una mejor idea, por ahora lo he intentado usando carruseles...

Lo otro que se me ocurre es poner cada tabla en un `div` y que cuando el usuario termine esa sección presione un botón siguiente y activar algún `hide`, pero como debería hacer para que todos los `div` queden exactamente en la misma posición?

[image]

Así se ve ahora mismo, es horrenda y muy larga. Yo quiero fraccionarla en unas 5 tablas con 7 preguntas cada una o 7 tablas con 5 preguntas, para que no haya que hacer scroll hacia abajo.

Cuando el usuario rellene todas las casillas (es un formulario), podrá avanzar sin cambiar de pagina, a la siguiente tabla. En el fondo es lo mismo, pero se vería mas ordenado y amigable completar un par de tablas más pequeñas que una sola gran tabla.

Lo intenté con carrusel y solo logre que la pagina se vea en blanco, o todo se pone por cualquier parte, ademas avanza solo.

Queria poner el codigo pero es demasiado largo y no me lo permite...

https://codeshare.io/alV1ly

Aqui pueden verlo

Comment: Buen día, podrías por favor mostrar a través de una imagen que es lo que tienes planeado, como sugerencia podrías poner una tabla con los datos mas relevantes y posteriormente poner un botón que abra un modal donde se visualice toda la información.

Comment: por favor agrega el código de lo que hasta ahora tienes

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Las preguntas sin código no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas como realizar una pregunta y evitar que te la cierren.

Comment: ¿Por qué  no divides las preguntas en varias páginas html ? Pones botones hacia atrás y adelante y vas cargando la página que corresponda. Es más puedes tener un índice por temas y navegas por páginas locales. Al margen que cualquier cambio o mantenimiento lo haces a una página sin afectar a otros. Una idea.

Answer (score 0):

Esta pregunta puede ser dirigida más hacia un [UX/UI](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) debido a que ellos son los encargados de hacer todo lo referente al diseño.

Y bien, ya que estamos, en este tipo de situaciones, te aconsejo que siempre antes de ponerte a codear tomes una hoja de papel y dibujes el resultado que quieres obtener porque si no perderás mucho tiempo intentando solucionarlo.

> Un buen diseño no solo ahorra tiempo en código, ayuda a los usuarios a
>   entender el sistema sin necesidad de preguntar cómo funciona.

Otras recomendaciones que te puedo hacer es que es elemental al mostrar una tabla poner los cabezales puesto que una captura al aire de elementos repetidos no nos ayuda a ayudarte. De igual manera ir testeando en [codepen](https://codepen.io) o en [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) te ayuda a ver el resultado sin ningún problema de tamaño.

Procedo a mostrarte un ejemplo de como pudiera quedar tu formulario

**[Ejemplo de una tabla con tabs](https://codepen.io/Mariyselita/pen/zYxdqYR)**

Recuerda que esto es ilustrativo, no olvides dibujarlo.

Saludos.